# RLlib PPO continuous actions seem to become nan after total_loss = inf?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, loss-function, gradient-descent, rllib

After some amount of training on a custom Multi-agent environment using RLlib's (1.4.0) PPO network, I found that my continuous actions turn into **nan** (explodes?) which is probably caused by a **bad gradient update** which in turn depends on the **loss/objective function**.

As I understand it, PPO's loss function relies on three terms:

1. The **PPO Gradient objective** [depends on outputs of old policy and new policy, the advantage, and the "clip" parameter=0.3, say]
2. The **Value Function Loss**
3. The **Entropy Loss** [mainly there to encourage exploration]

Total Loss = PPO Gradient objective (clipped) - vf_loss_coeff * VF Loss + entropy_coeff * entropy.

I have set entropy coeff to 0. So I am focusing on the other two functions contributing to the total loss. As seen below in the progress table, the relevant portion where the total loss becomes **inf** is the problem area. The only change I found is that the policy loss was all negative until **row #445**.

**So my question is:** Can anyone explain what policy loss is supposed to look like and if this is normal? How do I resolve this issue with continuous actions becoming nan after a while? Is it just a question of lowering the learning rate?

**EDIT**

Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68223500/rllib-ppo-reward-flat-lines-with-runtimewarning-mean-of-empty-slice) to the related question (if you need more context)

**END OF EDIT**

I would really appreciate any tips! Thank you!

|  | Total loss | policy loss | VF loss |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 430 | 6.068537 | -0.053691725999999995 | 6.102932 |
| 431 | 5.9919114 | -0.046943977000000005 | 6.0161843 |
| 432 | 8.134636 | -0.05247503 | 8.164852 |
| 433 | 4.222730599999999 | -0.048518334 | 4.2523246 |
| 434 | 6.563492 | -0.05237444 | 6.594456 |
| 435 | 8.171028999999999 | -0.048245672 | 8.198222999999999 |
| 436 | 8.948264 | -0.048484523 | 8.976327000000001 |
| 437 | 7.556602000000001 | -0.054372005 | 7.5880575 |
| 438 | 6.124418 | -0.05249534 | 6.155608999999999 |
| 439 | 4.267647 | -0.052565258 | 4.2978816 |
| 440 | 4.912957700000001 | -0.054498855 | 4.9448576 |
| 441 | 16.630292999999998 | -0.043477765999999994 | 16.656229 |
| 442 | 6.3149705 | -0.057527818 | 6.349851999999999 |
| 443 | 4.2269225 | -0.05446908599999999 | 4.260793700000001 |
| 444 | 9.503102 | -0.052135203 | 9.53277 |
| 445 | **inf** | **0.2436709** | **4.410831** |
| 446 | nan | -0.00029848056 | 22.596403 |
| 447 | nan | 0.00013323531 | 0.00043436907999999994 |
| 448 | nan | 1.5656527000000002e-05 | 0.0002645221 |
| 449 | nan | 1.3344318000000001e-05 | 0.0003139485 |
| 450 | nan | 6.941916999999999e-05 | 0.00025863337 |
| 451 | nan | 0.00015686743 | 0.00013607396 |
| 452 | nan | -5.0206604e-06 | 0.00027541115000000003 |
| 453 | nan | -4.5543664e-05 | 0.0004247162 |
| 454 | nan | 8.841756999999999e-05 | 0.00020278389999999998 |
| 455 | nan | -8.465959e-05 | 9.261127e-05 |
| 456 | nan | 3.8680790000000003e-05 | 0.00032097592999999995 |
| 457 | nan | 2.7373152999999996e-06 | 0.0005146417 |
| 458 | nan | -6.271608e-06 | 0.0013273798000000001 |
| 459 | nan | -0.00013192794 | 0.00030621013 |
| 460 | nan | 0.00038987884 | 0.00038019830000000004 |
| 461 | nan | -3.2747877999999998e-06 | 0.00031471922 |
| 462 | nan | -6.9349815e-05 | 0.00038836736000000006 |
| 463 | nan | -4.666238e-05 | 0.0002851575 |
| 464 | nan | -3.7067155e-05 | 0.00020161088 |
| 465 | nan | 3.0623291e-06 | 0.00019258813999999998 |
| 466 | nan | -8.599938e-06 | 0.00036465342000000005 |
| 467 | nan | -1.1529375e-05 | 0.00016500981 |
| 468 | nan | -3.0851965e-07 | 0.00022042097 |
| 469 | nan | -0.0001133984 | 0.00030230957999999997 |
| 470 | nan | -1.0735256e-05 | 0.00034000343000000003 |

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `RLLIB`'s PPO configuration of `grad_clip` is way too big (`grad_clip=40`). I changed it to `grad_clip=4` and it worked.

Comment: changing the grad_clip did not help for me

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem when running [the rllib example](https://github.com/Farama-Foundation/PettingZoo/blob/c96c813d0f8a13e54339071a8903d87cac66ef02/tutorials/rllib_pistonball.py). I also post my problem in [this issue](https://github.com/Farama-Foundation/PettingZoo/issues/637). I am also running PPO in a countious and bounded action space. The PPO output actions that are quite large and finally crash dued to Nan related error.

For me, it seems that when the log_std of the action normal distribution is too large, large actions(about 1e20) will appear. I copy the codes for calculate loss in RLlib(v1.10.0) ppo_torch_policy.py and paste them below.

```
logp_ratio = torch.exp(
    curr_action_dist.logp(train_batch[SampleBatch.ACTIONS]) -
    train_batch[SampleBatch.ACTION_LOGP])
action_kl = prev_action_dist.kl(curr_action_dist)
mean_kl_loss = reduce_mean_valid(action_kl)

curr_entropy = curr_action_dist.entropy()
mean_entropy = reduce_mean_valid(curr_entropy)

surrogate_loss = torch.min(
    train_batch[Postprocessing.ADVANTAGES] * logp_ratio,
    train_batch[Postprocessing.ADVANTAGES] * torch.clamp(
        logp_ratio, 1 - self.config["clip_param"],
                    1 + self.config["clip_param"]))
```

For that large actions, the logp `curr_action_dist.logp(train_batch[SampleBatch.ACTIONS])`computed by <class 'torch.distributions.normal.Normal'> will be -inf. And then `curr_action_dist.logp(train_batch[SampleBatch.ACTIONS]) -train_batch[SampleBatch.ACTION_LOGP])` return Nan. torch.min and torch.clamp will still keep the Nan output(refer to the [doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.minimum.html#torch-minimum)).

**So in conclusion, I guess that the Nan is caused by the -inf value of the log probability of very large actions, and the torch failed to clip it according to the the "clip" parameter.**

The difference is that I do not set entropy_coeff to zero. In my case, the std variance is encouraged to be as large as possible since the entropy is computed for the total normal distribution instead of the distribution restricted to the action space. I am not sure whether you get large σ as I do. In addition, I am using Pytorch, things may be different for Tf.